# Windows CMD - can't call .cmd file from .bat file

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, batch-file, cmd.exe

I created A.bat file inside that file i am trying to call B.cmd file

```
call B.cmd
```

When trying to invoke the below command in CMD Terminal

```
call A.bat
```

Output is

```
'B.cmd' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

How to call B.cmd inside A.bat ?

Comment: Check if your `b.cmd` is posessed in current drive and folder. Or use explicit file's drive/folder in CALL statement, i.e. `call c:\tmp\b.cmd`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know, do you need to use "call" but maybe this can help your problem;

```
start /b "B.cmd"
```

or without "/b"